# Can anyone check my css code for dropdown menu, cant center the navigation menu?

Tags: css

I am new in coding css, tried suggested answers related to my problem but nothing works, any help will be appreciated; I want to place my menu at the center of the page while retaining the container background covered the entire available width...

**here is my html code:**

```
   <div id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.htm">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="history.htm">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.htm#mission">Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.htm#bod">Board of Directors</a></li>
            <li><a href="location.htm">Location</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="SFO.htm">Facilities & Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Services >></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="im.htm">Internal Medicine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="obg.htm">OB-Gyne</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pedia.htm">Pediatrics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="surgery.htm">Surgery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dental.htm">Dental Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rehab.htm">Rehabilitation Medicine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ent.htm">Otorhinolaryngology(ENT)</a></li>
              </ul>
            <li><a href="facilities.htm">Facilities >></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="lab.htm">Laboratory-Tertiary Level</a></li>
                    <li><a href="i&cc.htm">Intensive & Critical Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="nnc.htm">Nursery & Neonatal Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="picu.htm">Pediatric Intensive Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pcu.htm">Pulmonary Care</a></li>
                    <li><a href="ecc.htm">Ear Care Center</a></li>
                    <li><a href="hdu.htm">Hemodialysis Unit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cardio.htm">Cardiac Diagnostics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rd.htm">Radiology Diagnostics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="obg.htm">OB-Gyne Diagnostics</a></li>
                </ul>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="hp.htm">Healthcare Plans</a>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="hmo.htm">Accredited HMOs</a></li>
            <li><a href="executive.htm">Executive Checkup</a></li>
            <li><a href="cc.htm">Credit Cards</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="hcp.htm">Doctors</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">""</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="career.htm">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="archive.htm">Archive</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.htm">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.htm">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**and my css code:**

```
#nav {
    Z-INDEX: 10;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: green;  
    position: relative;
    padding:3px;
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height:1.5em;
    float: none;
 }
#nav-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
 } 
#nav ul{
    Z-INDEX: 10;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    width: 1000px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: none;   
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    font-size: 13px;
    float: none;
 }

#nav li li{
    Z-INDEX: 10;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight: normal;
    list-style-position:outside;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid white;
    color: #fff;
 }

#nav a:link, #nav a:visited{
    display:block;
    padding:0px 5px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: green;
 }

#nav ul a:hover{
    Z-INDEX: 999;
    background: light-green;
    color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li ul a:hover{
    Z-INDEX: 999;
    background: green;
    color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li li a:hover{
    Z-INDEX: 999;
    background: light-green;
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a:hover{
    background: light-green;
    color: yellow;
    Z-INDEX: 999;
    position: relative;
}

#nav a:active{
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#nav li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    width:14em;
    top:1.3em;
    display:none;
}

#nav li ul a{
    width:14.65em;
    float:left;
}

#nav ul ul{
    top:auto;
    }

#nav li ul ul {
    left:14.65em;
    margin:0px 0 0 10px;
    }

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
    display:none;
    }
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: Post it in a jsfiddle.

Comment: one assumption would be to try margin: 0 auto; on #nav

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the `#nav` with another `div`.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="nav"></div>
</div>
```

Remove the `width` from `#nav`, and apply the following CSS:

```
#wrap {
    background: green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KKmG2/) - it works.

Comment: He already has selector `#nav-wrapper` in hes CSS but it's not used.

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen Didn't even notice that. Regardless of that, it wouldn't work, as you need to remove the width from `#nav`, as it is currently 100%.. additionally, you would need to add `background:green`.. http://jsfiddle.net/KKmG2/

Comment: Yeap true. Just thought that you could use that selector without creating a new.

Comment: Thanks Ville Rouhiainen!